# How do I stop Cocos2D from requiring standard definition resources (SD images)?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iPhone game with Cocos2d-iphone.

I want my game to only be available to the iPhone 4 AND iPad. Retina enabled for iPhone 4. I don't want the game to run on older devices.

Cocos2d will always ask me for -hd and non-hd files. If I don't provide the SD files, I get errors. I don't want that: is there a way to disable Cocos2d from trying to retrieve SD files, and only get -hd suffixed files by default?

Oh, and when the game is run by an iPad, the graphics will be the -hd ones as well. So the point is, I only want to have -hd files in my project.

What are the proper steps to edit Cocos2d's source for such?

Comment: "SD" means "Standard Definition", not "Simple Definition". FYI.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: I know that - it was Qwerty Bob who edited my title there.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would like a more straight-forward method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using cocos2d version >= 2.0, then you can change the value of a global variable found in `CCFileUtils.h`:

```
static NSString *__suffixiPad =@"-hd";
```

(Its default value is `@"-ipad"`.)

If you are using cocos2d version < 2.0, then you can find [here](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/blob/master/cocos2D/CCFileUtils+SDSDeviceSuffix.m) a category that I wrote to be able to transparently use -hd images created for the iPhone 4 on the iPad 1/2.

Actually, it does more than that, but if you add it to your project, then "-hd" images will be "automagically" used on the iPad 1/2 instead of their SD versions (which you could also not include in your project).

Let me know if you have any issues integrating this code.

Comment: If I changed my mind and just wanted to develop for iPhone 4(s), would just adding this code allow me to go to my game project and delete all files that don't have -hd suffixes?

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Can I use that code for commercial games?

Comment: One quick question: What I did was take your code and put it in a new file in my project named *CCFileUtils+SDSDeviceSuffix.m*. Was that all I had to do? Because I suspect that the code is doing nothing, and the reason my game begun working was something else (that recently failed).

Comment: you are right on the file part. about my code not working: have you possibly updated your cocos2s library? which version are you using?

Comment: Please, see my edited answer in case you are using cocos2d version >= 1.0.

Comment: Although I never did find that global variable you said. I am using 1.0.1.

Comment: Actually, I do believe it is still not working. My -hd graphics are not being used on my iPad. For some reason I still believe that your code is not being executed.

Comment: I am sorry about the version mismatch: the global variable is available in 2.0. About the code not being executed: either put a breakpoint or a log trace in `getDoubleResolutionImage` (in CCFileUtils+SDSDeviceSuffix.m). I have just checked with cocos2d version 1.0.1 and it works. Also, ensure that `CC_RETINA_DISPLAY_SUPPORT` (ccConfig.h) is set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If I would have been at your place.. I would have played with a trick.. Don't down vote the answer if you don't like.. But Its just a thing in my mind.

Use -hd images in the code directly.. iPhone 4 will handle it easily.. Older iPhones will show it much larger and it doesn't matter as you are not supporting them...
So instead of using Background.png , directly use Background-hd.png as it will work fine for iPhone 4.. Instead of wasting time on all these SD stuff.. I will directly use my -hd images for my work...

I can not say about new iPad.. But old iPad can easily use -hd images in code as you want.. For iPad I have directly used in my code earlier.. 
Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use -hd directly. While it works with older versions of cocos2d, in 1.1beta2 you will get an error.(issue 1045). In future versions, it is likely that you are expected to only refer to the files without the -hd / -ipad / -ipadhd suffixes.

Comment: thanks for telling.. But I din't use the latest version... As I started working on cocos2d-x instead of cocos2d and it used to work fine previously.. In that case you may give a higher resolution image.. I think it could directly support that... I'll check it today.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial might help](http://michaelgilkes.info/cocos2d-using-hd-images-for-ipad-in-a-universal-app/).

If you only provide -hd assets, you should only get errors regarding missing SD assets when running on iPad. The iPad doesn't have a Retina display, but it certainly is high resolution enough to be treated like one.

Since cocos2d passes all filename requests through the [fullPathFromRelativePath function in CCFileUtils](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_file_utils.html#a67d419fb53985832d34ddaa4cac1b2f6) it may be enough to modify this function to treat the iPad like an HD device and force it to load -hd assets on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st idea i can think of is to use @2x suffix for images (UIKit style) and you wont need to enable retina display in app.The problem is that on the ipad you'll have to write your own method to remove @2x suffix

the 2nd idea was to make a SD image..but only 1x1 pixels... it takes virtually no space at all ( 119 bytes with white pixel). Should work on ipad as-is

3rd idea:don't enable (or enable..doesn't make any difference) retina display but have the HD images as SD images.I've tested this on cocos2d v1.0.1 and it seems to work.Also..it should work on ipad

4th idea forcefully enable retina display in `ccConfig.h` (so that director won't ask you for the SD images on ipad) .I'm not sure about this one because there are quite a few tests that check for resolution, device and if it's retina and you'd have to edit all of them

these are just ideas off the top of my head..they may be wrong..but they're just ideas